# Real time Laravel

Tags: node.js, laravel, websocket, realtime

Решил написать проект с реалтаймом(что-то на подобии мессенджера). В качестве бэка буду использовать laravel, но есть вопрос о выборе тулза для реалтайма: либо laravel-echo-server, либо же node и redis в качестве mq. Склоняюсь ко второму варианту, но единственное, что отталкивает - это как реализовать приватные каналы на node? В LES это есть из-под коробки. Cуществует ли какой-то не костыльный способ реализовать это в связке с node?

Comment: Псоветовал бы использовать [centrifugo](https://github.com/centrifugal/centrifugo). Практически всё нужное реализзовано, "бери да используй". Недавно webrtc пришлось писать, в т.ч. с мессенжером, проверенная временем центрифуга на ура справляется с задачей.

Comment: а laravel не сторонний сервис?... Раз учебный проект всё с нуля пишите. (сарказм, если что)

Comment: https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets попробуй))